# Using Hibernate on JSP

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp

So i went to the website and downloaded hibernate release 4 and i extracted and i created a library in my eclipse and i added all the needed jars but it shows that my hibernate import is not working well.. am i importing them wrongly? any help would do. This are the highligted imports.

my question is am i missing something...or am i declaring them wrongly.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@page import="hibernate.Submenu"%>
<%@page import="hibernate.Menu"%>
<%@page import="Biz.MenuBiz"%>
<%@page import="hibernate.Inform"%>
<%@page import="Biz.InformBiz"%>
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%
String path = request.getContextPath();
String basePath = request.getScheme()+"://"+request.getServerName()+":"+request.getServerPort()+path+"/";
%>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Programming made easier</title>
</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no hibernate import anywhere. The classes from the ``hibernate`` package are not from the hibernate libraries, those are in the ``org.hibernate`` package.

Comment: how do i write that one? like this "org.hibernate.Submenu"

Comment: You can only import existing classes - ``org.hibernate.Submenu`` does not exist. I suspect it's your own class, in which case it does not belong into the ``org.hibernate`` package. What are you trying to do? What does the ``Submenu`` class do?

Comment: Don't write JSPs like this. Use a proper MVC separation instead of scriptlets.

Comment: thanks. I have an idea now

Comment: @chrylis any samples please? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it seems like something is missing , 
Not that an expert of JSP, but I see that you don't import stuff around the hibernate package. 
You do seem to import "java.util.*" - but what about the hibernate packages? Where do you import them? 
In addition, do you see the error at the server side? is Hibernate located in your web-inf/lib directory?